# How do I bind a Generic class?

Tags: java, generics, mockito, guice, jukito

When I try to mock a Dao using [Jukito](http://code.google.com/p/jukito/) I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at org.jukito.JukitoModule.addKeyDependency(JukitoModule.java:338)
    at org.jukito.JukitoModule.addInjectionPointDependencies(JukitoModule.java:330)
    at org.jukito.JukitoModule.addDependencies(JukitoModule.java:313)
```

The object I try to mock is a `ConcreteDao`.

```
public class ConcreteDao extends AbstractDao<MyDomain> {
}

public abstract class AbstractDao<T extends DatastoreObject> {
}
```

I read several posts on SO about this binding generics but I can't figure out a way to use `TypeLiteral` for my binding.

This is what I tried:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<AbstractDao<MyDomain>>(){}).to(ConcreteDao.class);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate in your question? It is not clear what exactly is the problem.

Comment: I reformulated the question. Hope it's better

Comment: Not really. I don't know Jukito and I might not be alone, could you post a JUnit test explaining where is exactly the issue :)

Comment: I reworked my code to mock interfaces instead of classes. It's working now. The good thing is that my code is now cleaner ;)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jukito in particular, but upon first glance this sounds like a bug (or bad error reporting ;) ). Out of curiosity, if you do `bind(new TypeLiteral<AbstractDao<MyDomain>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<ConcreteDao>(){});` instead, does it work? Looking at the JukitoModule source, it looks like it's expecting the `TypeLiteral`'s `Type` to be a `ParameterizedType` when it happens to be a `Class` (not a safe assumption, apparently). If you can create a small test to reproduce the bug, I'd file a bug with the Jukito project.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind like this:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<AbstractDao<MyDomain>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<ConcreteDao<MyDomain>>(){});
```

This is how you can retrieve the generic class:

```
class AbstractDao {
  protected final Class<T> clazz;

  @Inject
  public AbstractDao(TypeLiteral<T> type) {
    clazz = (Class<T>) type.getRawType();
  }
}
```

Subclasses of `AbstractDao` will need to pass entity specific `TypeLiteral`s to the parent class (`AbstractDao`):

```
class ConcreteDao extends AbstractDao<MyDomain> {
  @Inject
  public ConcreteDao(TypeLiteral<MyDomain> type) {
    super(type);
  }
}
```

Note that you can make your AbstractDao class non-abstract and implement basic CRUD operations, so that you can use it without the need to extend `AbstractDao` for each entity. You will just need a binding for each entity like this:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<GenericDao<User>>(){}).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

See my [blog-post](http://jamolkhon.blogspot.com/2012/07/generic-typesafe-dao-with-guice-and.html) for more information.